# method to obscure/encrypt peoples names in an simple fashion (and decrypt)

Tags: java, algorithm

I am looking to obscure peoples' names with something simple that prevents easy decryption to a layman without creating a longer string (just a few characters extra is OK).

**For Example**

```
Thomas --> U0Y71M
George --> ELDP3N
```

I just fabricated the above.  I would be able to reverse it so that I can restore the original text.

While I could do something like exchanging ASCII codes of the name, creating a mapping perhaps that is too easy to glance at a few names and figure out?

Is there anything else that might require more effort to decrypt?

Comment: What kind of characters can be used on names? Only a-z + A-Z or higher ascii codes like 周?

Comment: it may be good to think about: Why you are doing this. If you make the user think that information is not exposed, when in fact it is, that is not really a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base 64 encoding is good :)

**Code**

```
String name = "George";
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(name.getBytes());
System.out.println(encodedString);
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
System.out.println(new String(decodedBytes));
```

**Output**

```
R2Vvcmdl
George
```

**Reference**

https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode

Comment: also very easily detectable.

Comment: I think "prevents easy decryption to a layman" implies that this was OK.

Comment: So... your definition of a layman is a person running a Linux terminal with knowledge of how web requests commonly have their passwords encoded?  Of course its not encrypted, he didn't ask for that.  If you want to post an answer that allows actual encryption that can be reversed, give a solution yourself :).

Comment: That is perfect for my requirements, thanks !